# How to solve timeout in this codes?

Tags: algorithm, timeout

I need a help. the problem is finding a symmetric numbers when shining in a mirror. (ex. 0, 1, 11, 101, 1521 (o) but 1221 & 1010 is not.)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAqea.png)
Two numbers A and B are given with spaces between them.(input)
range is 0<=A, B<=10^18.

output is print symmetric numbers count from A to B.

ex) 0 100 (input) 
7(output)

this is my codes in c++, but this codes occurred timeout because of wide number range. how solve this problem?

```
int main()
{

    scanf("%d %d", &n,&m);

    for(int i=n;i<=m;i++)
    {
        char s[19];
        n=i;
        int len=0;

        do{ 
            s[len++]=n%10;
            n/=10; 
        } while(n>0);

        len--;
        int j = 0;

        for(j=0;j<=len/2;j++)
        {
            if(s[j]==s[len-j] && (s[j]==1 || s[j]==8 || s[j]==0))
                continue;

            if( (s[j]==2 && s[len-j]==5) || (s[j]==5 && s[len-j]==2))
                continue;

            break;
        }

        if(j>len/2)
            cnt++;
    }

    printf("%d\n",cnt);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First: Your question is really badly formatted, to the point of being barely readable. Please improve that. To answer your question: My guess would be that the solution to the problem is not no check all numbers between A and B, but to only generate numbers that have the desired property - i.e., only generate numbers that don't contain any non-mirrorable digits.

Answer (score 0):

You've gone through a very painful process to see which of *all* the numbers are mirrors.  Lukas Barth is on the right track, but it's even faster than that.  You don't need to construct the numbers; just count how many there are.

First of all, you don't care at all about the second half of the number; by construction, given the left half, the right half is unique.  Thus, all you have to do is to count left halves for each number length.  This will solve all counting for powers of 10 that are entirely included in the range.

This makes it *much* easier.  For the the ranges in which you have only part of the numbers (i.e. A and/or B is not a power of 10), you'll have to restrict leading digits on one end of the range or the other.

You're allowed leading zeros.  Thus, you have five possibilities for each digit: 0, 1, 8, 2, 5.  If you have an odd number of digits, then the middle digit must be its own mirror: 0, 1, 8.

So let's look at an example, 4-digit and 5-digit numbers.  For the 4-digit numbers, you need only the first two.  You have 5 possibilities for each of those digits.  This yields 5*5, or `25 four-digit mirror numbers`.

Now extend that for 5-digit numbers.  You already know that there are exactly 25 two-digit starts.  Add one of your three legal middle digits, and that gives 3*25, or `75 five-digit mirror numbers`.

Extending this to the full solution is left as an exercise for the student.